# Get different SOLR rows with on field value unique

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to get a list of  12 classifieds from SOLR, each classified has a field called User_id, which has to be different from the other nine, there fore all the classified listed has to be from a different user.

I've reading about facetes, but i dont't get the use for making what I want, I've tried some of there queries:

```
q=*:*&start=0&rows=12&fq=type:classifieds&fq=confirmed:1&fq=country:ES&fq={!tag=picture}picture:1&fq={!tag=date_created}date_created:[2006-12-09T00:00:00Z TO 2011-12-06T19:12:43Z]&group=true&group.field=user_id&sort=date_created desc

q=*:*&start=0&rows=12&fq=type:classifieds&fq=confirmed:1&fq=country:ES&fq={!tag=picture}picture:1&fq={!tag=date_created}date_created:[2006-12-09T00:00:00Z TO 2011-12-06T19:12:43Z]&facet=true&facet.field=user_id&facet.mincount=1&sort=date_created desc

q=*:*&start=0&rows=12&fq=type:classifieds&fq=confirmed:1&fq=country:ES&fq={!tag=picture}picture:1&fq={!tag=date_created}date_created:[2006-12-09T00:00:00Z TO 2011-12-06T19:12:43Z]&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.numFacetTerms=1&facet.limit=-1&facet.field=user_id&sort=date_created desc
```

But none of them work, all return classifieds with user_id repited.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Result Grouping](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing). In your case start by adding `group=true&group.field=user_id`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I've tried that and the response I have is:  "Cannot group on non string like field." The field type is numeric, and I searched how to group integers but found nothing :(

Comment: @Pablo copy it (with a `copyField`) to a string field, then group on that.